# How can I convert an image to a base64 string using Java?

Tags: java, string, base64

As the title indicates, I want to know how to convert an image to a base64 string in Java. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`Base64`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class.

If you're on pre-Java 8, have a look at one of the following resources:

- [The example at exampledepot.com](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/base64.html)
- or [Base64Coder - an open-source Base64 encoder/decoder in Java](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/)
- or the [Base64 class in the org.apache.commons.codec.binary package](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

Comment: I think you should add a simple example.

Answer (score 5):

java code to convert image to string

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test{
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Test/logo.png"));
        BufferedImage newImg;
        String imgstr;
 imgstr = encodeToString(img, "png");
        System.out.println(imgstr);
}
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
        String imageString = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageString;
    }
}
```

and can embed it in XSL as below

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0......."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) for encoding and decoding

Comment: Usually it is worth adding a simple example or a small excerpt from the link, to provide more context and increase the value of the answer.

Comment: You should answer the question, not refer to another source to look for the answer there - that's what Google exists for.